# Why send() doesn't trigger SIGPIPE for a closed TCP connection?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a simple server and a simple client based on TCP connection in Linux. I discover that when the server is closed, the first following `send()` from the client will be successful (and return the bytes send). Only the second following `send()` from the client will trigger SIGPIPE.

The following code illustrates this phenomenon. After the client is connected to the server, I close the socket of the server, and then let the client send two successive messages to the server. The first `send()` will be successful, while the second `send()` will trigger SIGPIPE.

Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define SERVER_SOCK 32413
#define LISTEN_BACKLOG 20

int main() {
    int server_sock, client_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client_addr);

    // Create socket
    server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Set address and port
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_SOCK);

    // Bind to port and begin listening
    bind(server_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    listen(server_sock, LISTEN_BACKLOG);
    printf("Server is listening\n");

    // Accept client socket
    client_sock = accept(server_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, &client_len);
    printf("Connection accepted\n");

    // Close all socket after pressing enter
    printf("Press enter to close server");
    getchar();
    close(server_sock);
    close(client_sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define SERVER_SOCK 32413

int main() {
    // Create socket
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Connect to server
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_SOCK);
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
    printf("Connected\n");

    // Send message after pressing enter
    printf("Press enter to send message");
    getchar();
    printf("1st send: %ld\n", send(sock, "one", 3, 0));
    printf("2nd send: %ld\n", send(sock, "two", 3, 0));

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the server is:

```
Server is listening
Connection accepted
Press enter to close server
```

The output of the client is:

```
Connected
Press enter to send message
1st send: 3
```

So what's going on? Why is the first `send()` successful? Isn't it supposed to trigger SIGPIPE?

Comment: With the server, did you press enter?

Comment: Yes. I pressed enter.